# TYPO3 change meta value in specified tt_news category

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

I have a question about tt_news and SEO. I would like to change some meta value in news from specified category. I try with this code but it didn't work:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_ttnews|tt_news > 0] && [globalVar = GP:tx_ttnews|cat = 13]
   page = PAGE
   page.meta.robots = noindex
[global]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why `page=PAGE` again? if your URL looks like `&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=123&tx_ttnews[cat]=13` and you dropped the whole FE cache it should work.

Comment: I thought that in order to change the `meta` tag I need to use `page = PAGE`

Comment: I assume that you have declared `page` already BEFORE adding this condition

Comment: Yes in another TS file (with whole PAGE stuff). Now I see what you mean. I have one more question - the fragment of `&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=123&tx_ttnews[cat]=13` I should insert in `globalVar` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `[globalVar = GP:param = foo]` checks if `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays (in this order) contains the `param` with value `foo`, but it soen't check the record for used categories, therefore you need to write custom condition ([reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-userfunc)) into `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` (mandatory location for TYPO3 6.x! in 4.x that would be common `typo3conf/localconf_local.php`) which will check if there's param with single news and then will check `tt_news_cat_mm` table for relations between News and Category, ready to use sample is:

```php
/** For ext:tt_news only! (not for ext:news) */
function user_ttNewsInCat($catUid) {
    $newsParams = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('tx_ttnews');

    // If news is in params then check categories, otherwise skip it
    if (!is_null($newsParams) && is_array($newsParams) && intval($newsParams['tt_news']) > 0) {
        $newsUid = intval($newsParams['tt_news']);
        $matchesInMM = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('*', 'tt_news_cat_mm', "uid_local={$newsUid} AND uid_foreign={$catUid}");

        if (count($matchesInMM)>0) return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

And its usage in typoscript is:

```
[userFunc = user_ttNewsInCat(13)]
  page.meta.robots = noindex
[end]
```

Comment: Work like a charm :) Thanks!